# How can I change keyboard layout for recovery mode? (wrong keyboard layout in recovery mode)

Tags: grub2, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I tried to boot my PC then it got stuck in AppArmor infinite loop ( start job initialization...)
then I booted in recovery mode in order to disable the AppArmor service to fix it
but it's loaded in my non-English keyboard. all the characters I type are solid squares.
How can I recover it?

Comment: while installing Ubuntu what was the language set?

Comment: my first keyboard layout was Persian(Farsi) and the second one was English. I didn't think it would matter much. I just let the AppArmor service do its thing for about an hour then I got the login screen. but I'm still curious if it's possible to change the language at that state. thanks

Comment: Hi.. I Tried to reproduce it with different language while installing.. But I am not able to produce the same problem..